# Finding a word in text

Tags: java, pattern-matching, match, java.util.scanner

The following code seems to work fine

```
String key = "jumps"   
String text = "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";  
if (text.matches(".*\\b"+key+"\\b.*"))
    System.out.println("Match");
```

The if statement is TRUE and I get the MATCH to printout.
But this is what I need to do:
Create a file called text.txt and put in it "the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog".

```
String text = new Scanner( new File("test.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
String key = "jumps" 
if (text.matches(".*\\b"+key+"\\b.*"))
    System.out.println("Match");
```

This match only seems to work if there is only one line in the test.txt file.
If there is one line in the file - the if statement is TRUE.
If I create the file with two lines -
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog

then the if statement NEVER seems to be true.
Any ideas as to why and what I can do to get this match to work with the file?

Comment: Why not use [String's `indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use [`indexOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf%28java.lang.String%29)?

For example:

```
String text = new Scanner( new File("test.txt") ).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
String key = "jumps";
if (Arrays.asList(text.split("[\\s]")).indexOf(key) != -1)
    System.out.println("Match");
else
    System.out.println("No match");
```

The nice thing about this solution is that it also gives you which word in the sequence it is; however, it might not be fast for very large Strings.

If you really want to use a Regular Expression, you need to use `\s`, because new lines can be represented by `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n` [and \s can be any of these](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum). So, you would need something like this:

EDIT: Use the following regex instead: `"(?s:.*\\b"+key+"\\b.*)"`.

```
if (text.matches("(.|\\s)*\\b"+key+"\\b(.|\\s)*"))
    System.out.println("Regex: Match");
else
    System.out.println("Regex: No match");
```

If you are going to be finding words in very large files, you may want to check out [StringSearch](http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/). Just download the `jar`, add it to your `classpath`, and make sure you `import com.eaio.stringsearch.*;`

```
BNDMWildcards bndm = new BNDMWildcards();
int bndmIdx = 0;
int stopIdx = text.length();
boolean isFound = false;

while(!isFound && (bndmIdx = bndm.searchString(text, bndmIdx, stopIdx, "."+key+".")) != -1){
    char[] textChars = text.toCharArray();
    if(Character.isWhitespace(textChars[bndmIdx]) && Character.isWhitespace(textChars[bndmIdx+key.length()+1])){
        System.out.println("BNDM: Match");
        isFound = true;
    }
}
if(!isFound)
    System.out.println("BNDM: No match");
```

I am not sure speed-wise how this method compares to the other two. My guess is it will take longer for short `text`, but be faster when the `text` is very long.

EDIT: The previous `regex` contains the possibility to cause a `StackOverflowException` (perfect for this site!)- a problem I should have seen. That is because it is creating an enormous number of sub-expressions as it attempts to search `text`.

An alternative regex you can try is `"(?s:.*\\b"+key+"\\b.*)"`. This enabled [DOTALL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL), forcing the `.` to match all characters. It should only create a single subexpression.

Comment: Hi.. How do I make indexOf do only whole words? If I am looking for "he", I don't want to find "her". And there might be "," or "." or end of line after the word, so I can't just look for " ". Thanks.

Comment: Hi. Well I have to say that this regex does the correct thing that I wanted. The problem though is that it very, very slow. And any time that I am comparing to a string of more than around 150 characters, it hangs and doesn't come back in the 10 minutes that I waited.  The only change that I made was changing "(.|\\n)*\\b"+key+"\\b(.|\\n)*". My wrong way works instantaneously.

Comment: Wow. Thanks! Yes, your solution does the search and it returns almost instantaneously. So thanks everyone for their advice. I am curious though. What is the inherent difference in the two searches that makes the old way so much less efficient? Is it the "|" operator?

Comment: @Harry The problem was that it was creating a large number of [groups](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) as it tried to evaluate the expression. This can quickly lead to a `StackOverflowException` if you do not have much memory allocated to Java. If you have a lot, it will just run for a long time.

If this answer helped, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

`.` does not match the newline character, so when you have a new line, it fails. Use `\s` to match newline characters.

I am not a regex pro, but `(.|\s)` is *one* way to combine the two, using `|` (symbol for OR). The combination should match any character, including newline characters. Thus, your expression becomes

`"(.|\\s)*\\b" + key + "\\b(.|\\s)*"`

Comment: Sorry maybe I am being a little thick here but I tried what I thought that you meant. May I please ask you to be a little more specific as to how I change (".*\\b"+key+"\\b.*") since I don't want to affect that I am looking only for whole words. Thanks for the indulgence.

Comment: @harry I think I made a mistake and you caught it. Updated the answer.

Comment: Appreciate the help but having this - if (text.matches("(.|\\n)*\\b"+key+"\\b(.|\\n)*")) still works when there is only one line and does not work when there are more than one line.

Comment: @Harry I actually downloaded Netbeans and solved this one for you. It looks like \n doesn't always catch all of the characters between lines (especially for files saved by Notepad or Netbeans for Windows). I reverted to using \s, but left in \b to keep the word boundary. Tested and it works.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate your help. This does work correctly. The problem I am finding is that adding the \s makes the matching very, very, slow. In fact if I try to match something that is more than around 150 chars on my computer, it hangs and doesn't seem to return from the match. It works fine, albeit slowly on shorter strings.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this method?

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
    String text = "" ;
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        text=text+scanner.nextLine();
    }
 if (text.matches(".*\\b"+key+"\\b.*"))
System.out.println("Match");
```